# And/or SQL statement

Tags: sql, aginity

I'm struggling to get a SQL statement to run.

I need to have an `and` / `or` statement which gives me:

```
Where Condition 1 is true
OR
Where both Condition 2 AND Condition 3 are true. (not only one of them)
```

Appreciate some ideas :)

Comment: set the condition 2 and 3 together in brackets `(` and `)`. Show your current attempt.

Comment: The order of precedence is `not - and - or`, in your case you don't need brackets, but you should still add them, it helps reading/understanding.

Comment: I believe that expression `condition1 or condition2 and condition3` do what you want since `and` has higher priority over `or`.

Comment: thank you guys.. using bracket and understanding the priority helped :)

Answer (score -1):

You can split them with parenthesis, you also only need to define 'WHERE' once. Example:

```
WHERE
    {condition_1} or ({condition_2} and {condition_3})
```

Edit: You don't technically require parenthesis due to AND having a higher precedence than OR, but it makes it much easier to read and see at a glance exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Just seen. Also comments are not answers you can approve and have documented as working answers.